# xkeyval -- read keys from file

Tags: expansion, key-value, xkeyval

I want to read `xkeyval` options from an external file, like:

```latex
\setkeys{my@keys}{\input{conf}}
```

I tried several combinations of `\edef` and `\expandafter`, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Best regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't `\edef` an `\input` because it isn't expandable. You have to first read the contents of the file to a temporary variable and then pass that to `\setkeys`.

Here's an `expl3` implementation of `\setkeysFile`. It's the same as the standard `\setkeys` except that the second argument is a file that (should) contain a comma separated list of key-value pairs.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{conf.tex}
hello = world :D,
goodnews = everyone!,
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{my@keys}{hello}{\def\towhom{#1}}
\define@key{my@keys}{goodnews}{\def\who{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__nicolas_setkeys_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \setkeysFile { m m }
  {
    \file_get:nnNTF {#2} {} \l__nicolas_setkeys_tl
      { \exp_args:NnV \setkeys {#1} \l__nicolas_setkeys_tl }
      { \__kernel_msg_error:nnn { kernel } { file-not-found } {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setkeysFile{my@keys}{conf}

Hello \towhom

Good news \who

\end{document}
```

this prints:

> [image]

Comment: `\exp_args:NnV \setkeys{#1} \l__nicolas_setkeys_tl` already supplies the braces and is more correct code anyhow. The `\ior_open:Nn` business is useless.

Comment: Thanks :-) But why more correct? Oh, nevermind, it's because `V` gets the value of a register, and a register is an `N` type. Am I correct?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Because a `V`-type argument _must_ be a single token

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks! Some day I'll learn how to use `expl3` properly :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I took the liberty of streamlining your code.

Comment: @egreg Oh, I saw right after you did. Grazie :-) Much more elegant.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. My texlive distrib did not have `\get_file` used `catchfile`'s `CatchFileEdef` instead.